# Netbeans don't apply changes after save

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working with Netbeans 11.3 on a JSP project.

I am usually solving this problem this way

1. Click Clean and Build
2. If necessary I stop this [image: Stop Tomcat Server Netbeans]
3. Click Debug Project

**This takes up 30 seconds each try. Is there a smarter way or plugin?**

The Netbeans Properties[image: Netbeans Properties]

Comment: which changes are not applied ? copy static resources, compile on save, reloading the page based on jsp ?

Comment: Do you have this  `antiResourceLocking="true"` in `tomcat/conf/context.xml` ?

Comment: @Anthony It's Javaclasses and JSP

Comment: @AnishB. Sadly no...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after big steps in my project I found it by accident of Netbeans, where I had to disable compile on save.

Then I found this symbole:

[image]

It solves this problem, finally. :D

Answer (score 0):

I looked up your issue on google, and it looks like this is a bug that more than one person has faced on more than one version of Netbeans. There are bug reports of situations like this happening in Netbeans 6 and Netbeans 8. Apparently the only thing that worked for those who faced the bug was to start a new project and copy paste their code into that. Try making another project and see if this problem persists on that project.